# Extract data from the database to a map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to query data to a map :

```java
@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserEntity, String> {

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT (u.userId, u) FROM UserEntity u WHERE userId in (:userIds)")
    Map<String, UserEntity> findAllByUserIdIn(@Param("userIds") Collection<String> userIds);
```

But I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} [SELECT DISTINCT (u.userId, u) FROM com.telefire.device.server.users.model.UserEntity u WHERE userId in (:userIds)]
...
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: {vector} [SELECT DISTINCT (u.userId, u) FROM com.telefire.device.server.users.model.UserEntity u WHERE userId in (:userIds)]
```

JPA doesn't allow this?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I think that you wrote wrong query. Maybe try this SELECT DISTINCT u.userId, u FROM UserEntity u WHERE userId in (:userIds).
Other way is to just use findAllByUserIdIn without @Query and extract list, then use java stream to make it to map using Collectors.groupingBy.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but it didn't work. I want to do it without the stream, but when I'm extracting the data from the db...

Comment: I understand that it cannot do a distinct on __u__ that would imply doing a distinct on __u.*__ : all the fields that __u__ could contain.

Comment: DISTINCT is function of single parameter, so it can not contain char `,`.

Try something like this:

`SELECT DISTINCT (u.userId), u FROM UserEntity u WHERE userId in (:userIds)`.
I am not sure will this give you right result, like @MarcLeBihan wrote in comments, but it will remove syntax error that you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The exception means the Query syntax is not right.

Please check: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

second option add nativeQuery = true

```
    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT (u.userId, u) FROM UserEntity u WHERE userId in (:userIds)",nativeQuery = true)
```

third option add value =:

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT (u.userId, u) FROM UserEntity u WHERE userId in (:userIds)",nativeQuery = true)
```